# Does JProfiler Have A Reachability Scope View Like YourKit?

Tags: jprofiler

I am analysing a heap dump created by jmap.

YourKit has a "Reachability scope" which shows objects distributed according to their reachability scope, i.e. on how/whether they are reachable from GC roots
http://www.yourkit.com/docs/95/help/reachability.jsp

I am interested in seeing the "Objects unreachable from GC roots but not yet collected".

Does JProfiler have such a view?

For that matter, is there anyway to get this using jhat, VisualVM or IBM MAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not, but I've added this for 8.1, there will be an inspection "Unreachable objects" in the heap walker.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about inspection, but to see unreachable objects in a **heap dump**, check the "Customize Analysis" in the file selection dialog. Then uncheck "Perform full GC" in the analysis options.

I still don't know how to look at the set of unreachable objects, but they will be there in the full set of objects.

Comment: @IngoKegel - any comments?